# Multiple div id's in one line not displaying inline

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with getting the following divs in the last line with the city, state, and zip code to fall in one line. I have added a css class with the display set to inline, but it is not working or anything else I tried. Is there something I am doing wrong. This seemed like a pretty easy fix, but it is not turning out like that.

```css
.confirmshippinginfo {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 120px;
  font-size: .75em;
}
.confirmshippinginfoinline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="confirmshippinginfo">
  <span class="spanmediumfontbold"><p>Shipping to:</p></span>
  <p>
    <div id="name">John Smith</div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <div id="address1">101 Main St</div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <div id="address2">APT #2</div>
  </p>
  <div class="confirmshippinginfoinline">
    <div id="confirmcity">New York</div>,
    <div id="confirmstate">NY</div>
    <div id="confirmzip">11201</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the inline div's children display inline. Otherwise, you're simply drawing block elements inside an inline one.

```css
.confirmshippinginfo {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 120px;
  font-size: .75em;
}
.confirmshippinginfoinline div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="confirmshippinginfo">
  <span class="spanmediumfontbold"><p>Shipping to:</p></span>
  <p>
    <div id="name">name</div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <div id="address1">address1</div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <div id="address2">address2</div>
  </p>
  <div class="confirmshippinginfoinline">
    <div id="confirmcity">city</div>,
    <div id="confirmstate">state</div>
    <div id="confirmzip">zip</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following

Update

```
.confirmshippinginfoinline {
  display: inline;
}
```

to

```
.confirmshippinginfoinline div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made the container inline instead of the divs that you want to be inline. Take a look at the changes to the css:

**Changed line:**

```
.confirmshippinginfoinline div {
  display: inline;
}
```

**Full Code Snippets:**

```css
.confirmshippinginfo {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 120px;
  font-size: .75em;
}
.confirmshippinginfoinline div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="confirmshippinginfo">
  <span class="spanmediumfontbold"><p>Shipping to:</p></span>
  <p>
    <div id="name">John Smith</div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <div id="address1">101 Main St</div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <div id="address2">APT #2</div>
  </p>
  <div class="confirmshippinginfoinline">
    <div id="confirmcity">New York</div>,
    <div id="confirmstate">NY</div>
    <div id="confirmzip">11201</div>
  </div>
```